# gatsby -v bash: gatsby: command not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

Any help would be appreciated.

I have created package.json by

```
npm init
```

Installed gatsby and gatsby-cli modules as below:

```
npm install gatsby gatsby-cli
```

Opened the terminal to check the gatsby version

```
gatsby -v
```

Its giving me the error:

> $ gatsby -v bash: gatsby: command not found

I could see similar problem raised on stack overflow, but the solution provided there is not helping me to resolve.

Comment: `gatsby` insyny PATH. install it globally `-g` or use with path

Comment: The solutions provided there is not working for me, hence posted new question!

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2023/04/installing-gatsby/) for a few different approaches to installing `gatsby-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `gatsby` and `gatsby-cli` are installed locally in project?

If it is, you can alternatively execute command via `"script"` attribrute in package.json or run it directly via `node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: I just intalled gatsby and gatsby-cli modules via npm command. Do I need to install it locally?

Comment: `gatsby-cli` should be install globally and `gatsby` should be install locally